# Get point cloud of object in specific position on the image

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

I have an RGBD camera and using ROS and PCL for further point cloud processing.

**Question:**

Is it possible to get the point cloud of the object if I know the position relative to the camera?

For example, I know that the object will be in the centre of the image, so I don't want to capture all noise around and get only the point cloud of the object (and possibly points around it, not the environment around object).

I'm new to PCL and ROS, so any comments and advises will be useful!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If its filtering point clouds you can take a look at https://pcl-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/passthrough.html#passthrough .
Points are usually reported in metres. So its not too hard to allow only a certain area through.

Comment: Thank you, will be useful! But also find function pcl::CropBox< pcl::PCLPointCloud2 >. As I understand it is doing the same?

Comment: Better use `CropBox`, as `passthrough` will only filter a single field/axis.